# NZBGet - Installation problem. nzbget: command not found

Tags: plex

I have followed the instructions for installing NZBGet from the official [page](https://nzbget.net/installation-on-linux). I'm installing to a Rasberry Pi on Rasbian Jessie 3. It's 32 bit OS.

Following the installation instructions, when I run:

```
/nzbget -s
```

I get the error code:

> -bash: nzbget: command not found

It does work when I run it with:

```
strace ./nzbget -s
```

Running "file nzbget" returns:

> nzbget: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

The file is definitely in the directory. All users have execute permissions.
[Link to my nzbget directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfnJI.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command starts with a slash. Not a ./

/ Means look in the root directory.  ./ Means local